# Can I license a program containing data from a video game?

Tags: licensing, gaming

Let's say I want to release a program, written in Java, that is a sort of encyclopedia containing data about a game. This program would contain images from the game, obtained via screenshot, and some of them processed in a program like GIMP. The purpose of these images would be to illustrate about stuff that exists in the game, and not to be a part of the interface of the program (like the appearance of the interface's controls). I would like to license this program with the MIT License (Expat).

Is it possible? If not, can I release these images in some other way and make my program load them from the outside?

Searching for the answer on Google was nigh impossible (or I don't know the correct search terms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These images would be clearly copyrighted. But would it be fair for you to use them nonetheless? At least in the US there is something called "[Fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)".

For example, this [Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aoeiii-cover.jpg) is a low res image of a game box and contains this fair use related statement:

> *This image is cover art for a video game, and its copyright is most likely held by the game's publisher or developer. It is believed that the use of low-resolution images of game cover art*
>
> - *to visually identify the game in question*
> - *on the English Wikipedia, hosted on servers in the United States by the non-profit Wikimedia Foundation,*
>
> *constitutes fair use under United States copyright law. Other uses of this image may be copyright infringement. For more information, see Wikipedia:Non-free content.* [...]

The question is therefore whether or not your planned usage would be fair use or not.
A few illustrative images may be.

A database with 100 or 1000 screenshots may not and therefore you would be "infringing" of the game developers/authors/owner copyrights.

Your best course of action is to ask for an explicit written permission to the game developer.

See also [Am I allowed to use these gifs for my game?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/am-i-allowed-to-use-these-gifs-for-my-game)